# singularity run and execute command

Tags: bash, singularity-container

I know how to run a singularity:

```
singularity run /mn/sarpanitu/singularity/test/fenics-and-more.img
```

Is there a way to do a one line (or more) to run the previous command, and then in singularity run `echo "hi there"` ? (Of course, I will use something more complex than hi there in production). Once this is done, I want my singularity to still be well and alive for interactive use.

So something like the intent of:

```
singularity run /mn/sarpanitu/singularity/test/fenics-and-more.img -bash-command echo "hi there"
```

or

```
singularity run /mn/sarpanitu/singularity/test/fenics-and-more.img -run-script-at-startup script.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very related to the following question: [bash script to perform action in a singularity container it opens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51037873/bash-script-to-perform-action-in-a-singularity-container-it-opens/51944260#51944260) . Solution is posted there, basically using the `-c` option and spawning a bash console.

Answer (score 2):

Use `exec`, for executing a command within container instead of `run`. Add the shell and the script as parameters.

```
singularity exec /mn/sarpanitu/singularity/test/fenics-and-more.img /bin/sh script.sh
```

Also, add the execution of parameter as a default runtime command in the runscript part.

```
%runscript
  exec "$@"
```

Comment: Not working, as I do not get a singularity prompt using only exec. I would like to open singularity, execute a set of commands, and get my singularity prompt.