# Run script before getting prompt in singularity shell

Tags: docker, singularity-container

I have built a Docker container with a Docker file that ends with `WORKDIR /where/I/will/work` and when I spin up the container, I can get to work.  Unfortunately, my remote system won't allow Docker containers, so I converted it to a singularity container.  Everything works great, except that it drops me into a bind of my local directory, which is not where I want to be.

```
singularity shell --bind /different/src/dir:/a/dest/dir my_image.sif
```

This does almost everything I want, except for the aforementioned starting directory.

I'd like to run a script just after entering the shell that is simply `cd /where/I/want/to/be`.  There are a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51040864/singularity-run-and-execute-command) of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51037873/bash-script-to-perform-action-in-a-singularity-container-it-opens/51944260#51944260) with answers that no longer work because the meaning of the `-c` flag has changed.

I will also accept and answer that has me make a change to the Dockerfile, but I don't know what that could be because the Docker image works like I want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on [singularity shell](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.1/user-guide/cli/singularity_shell.html), the way to get what I want is to do

```
singularity shell --bind /different/src/dir:/a/dest/dir --pwd /where/I/want/to/be my_image.sif
```

The help message has it hidden a little bit under -p/--pid and mentions payloads and such that make it seem like it does something different.  I suspect that help is common with the exec command where the language would make more sense.